# Text processing and detection from a specific dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a text in English that I want to process to detect specific entries that I have in another dictionary in Python (example entry: mass spectroscopy). Those entries are very important as they need to be matched for later annotation. In order to do that I need to either add many forms of each entry (like plurals, acronyms etc.) or find a way to do the intelligent processing . Not only does the brute approach take much more time (for me), but I might not be able to resolve all the situations (I want mass spectroscopy, possibly spectroscopy, but not mass). I am not looking for a solutions, I just need guidelines how to approach the problem and which toolkit to use. The dictionary is growing and an intelligent approach would be preferred.

I have found NLTK in Python, but I am not sure how to use my dict in addition or instead of the built-in corpora.

Example - I have a sentence:
[u'Liquid', u'biopsies', u'based', u'on', u'circulating', u'cell-free', u'DNA', u'(cfDNA)', u'analysis', u'are', u'described', u'as', u'surrogate', u'samples', u'for', u'molecular', u'analysis.']
I have a dict with {'Liquid biopsy':['Blood for analysis'],'cfDNA':['Blood for analysis']}. The arrays are used on purpose so they are both the same object, thus trying to create aliases in a dict.

How do I match my entries to the text?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be more helpful if you showed us the code example of your imagined workflow.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service; it's centered on specific programming problems.

Comment: Sorry, I added a very concrete example, from my use case. Both text and dictionary are much larger.

Answer (score 1):

if i didn't misunderstand you, you want to check the dictionary items with the list items. Then print the results to the console.

```
dict_1={"Liquid Biopsy":"Blood for analysis","cfDNA":"Blood for analysis","Liquid Biopsies":"Blood for analysis"}
list_1=[u'Liquid', u'biopsies', u'based', u'on', u'circulating', u'cell-free', u'DNA', u'(cfDNA)', u'analysis', u'are', u'described', u'as', u'surrogate', u'samples', u'for', u'molecular', u'analysis.']
string_1=" ".join(list_1).lower()
for i in dict_1:
    if i.lower() in string_1:
        print("Key: {}\nValue: {}\n".format(i,dict_1[i]))
```

I used the above codes and the console printed the below results.

```
Key: Liquid Biopsies
Value: Blood for analysis

Key: cfDNA
Value: Blood for analysis


Process finished with exit code 0
```