# How to catch a dictionary key from a plain text?

Tags: python, dictionary

The subject of the study was taken from [Text processing and detection from a specific dictionary in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43988958/text-processing-and-detection-from-a-specific-dictionary-in-python/43989724#43989724) topic. Perhaps i misunderstood the OP's problem but i have tried to improve the codes. So, perhaps my question can be a bit different. Before explaining what i wanted to do, let me share the codes with you:

```
dict_1={"Liquid Biopsy":"Blood for analysis","cfDNA":"Blood for analysis"}
list_1=[u'Liquid', u'biopsy',u'based', u'on', u'circulating', u'cell-free', u'DNA', u'(cfDNA)', u'analysis', u'are', u'described', u'as', u'surrogate', u'samples', u'for', u'molecular', u'analysis.']
for i in dict_1:
    if i.lower() in " ".join(list_1).lower():
        print("Key: {}\nValue: {}\n".format(i,dict_1[i]))
```

These codes can catch the dictionary keys from a plain text which was written in `list_1`. However, when i was studying with this codes, i wondered what if some dictionary keys repeat in `list_1`. Then i wrote same keys two times in this `list_1`. And the above codes didn't recognize the repeated ones, the program gave the same result as below.

```
Key: cfDNA
Value: Blood for analysis

Key: Liquid Biopsy
Value: Blood for analysis


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Then i tried to change my method and wrote a different code which is given below:

```
dict_1={"Liquid Biopsy":"Blood for analysis","cfDNA":"Blood for analysis"}
list_1=[u'Liquid', u'biopsy',u'based', u'on', u'circulating', u'cell-free', "cfdna",u'DNA', u'(cfDNA)', u'analysis', u'are', u'described', u'as', u'surrogate', u'samples', u'for', u'molecular', u'analysis.']
for i in list_1:
    for j in dict_1:
        for k in j.split():
            count=0
            if k.lower() in i.lower():
                count+=1
                print("Key: {}\nValue: {}\nCount: {}\nDescription: Came from '{}'\n".format(j, dict_1[j],str(count),i))
```

But it was obvious, the last codes would give undesirable result. As can be seen at the below, the program catch both `liquid` and `biopsy` words from the `list_1`. `cfDNA` was written second times in the `list_1` so the program catches two times. But is it possible to write the result one time but sum up the catch time?

```
Key: Liquid Biopsy
Value: Blood for analysis
Count: 1
Description: Came from 'Liquid'

Key: Liquid Biopsy
Value: Blood for analysis
Count: 1
Description: Came from 'biopsy'

Key: cfDNA
Value: Blood for analysis
Count: 1
Description: Came from 'cfdna'

Key: cfDNA
Value: Blood for analysis
Count: 1
Description: Came from '(cfDNA)'


Process finished with exit code 0
```

I hope you understand what i wanted to do. I want to catch all of the keys which is written in a text. And also i want to count how many times, these keys repeat in a text.

Comment: can you share your input ? if it's a file or a list or something else ?

Comment: it's a list that defined in the codes as list_1.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood correctly, you want to find the number of times a "keyword" appears in a text. You can use the "re" module for this.

```
import re

dict_1={"Liquid Biopsy":"Blood for analysis","cfDNA":"Blood for analysis", "asfdafaf":"dunno"}
list_1=[u'Liquid', u'biopsy',u'based', u'on', u'circulating', u'cell-free', "cfdna",u'DNA', u'(cfDNA)', u'analysis', u'are', u'described', u'as', u'surrogate', u'samples', u'for', u'molecular', u'analysis.']

text = ' '.join(list_1).lower()

for key in dict_1:
    n = len(re.findall(key.lower(), text))
    if n > 0:
        print('Key:', key)
        print('Value:', dict_1[key])
        print('n:', n)
        print()
```

Comment: Yes, that's what i wanted to do. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Recently i have learned a new method about counting how many times does a dictionary key repeat in a plain text without importing "re" module. Perhaps it's suitable to put another method in this topic.

```
dict_1={"Liquid Biopsy":"Blood for analysis","cfDNA":"Blood for analysis"}
list_1=[u'Liquid', u'biopsy', u'liquid', u'biopsy',u'based',u'cfdna' ,u'on', u'circulating', u'cell-free', u'DNA', u'(cfDNA)', u'analysis', u'are', u'described', u'as', u'surrogate', u'samples', u'for', u'molecular', u'analysis.']
string_1=" ".join(list_1).lower()
for i in dict_1:
    if i.lower() in string_1:
        print("Key: {}\nValue: {}\nCount: {}\n".format(i,dict_1[i],string_1.count(i.lower())))
```

The above codes give almost the same results with the method of importing re module. The difference is, it doesnt't write the keys two times. So it's a bit similar to the first code structure which was written in the first post.

```
Key: Liquid Biopsy
Value: Blood for analysis
Count: 2

Key: cfDNA
Value: Blood for analysis
Count: 2


Process finished with exit code 0
```